# OAuth2Config: IllegalStateException: For MAC signing you do not need to specify the verifier key separately

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to create a project that uses Spring Security with JWT token. However when I deploy it I get the following error on the `tokenEnhancer()` method in `SecurityConfig`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'tokenEnhancer' defined 
in testproject.security.OAuth2Config: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: For MAC signing you 
do not need to specify the verifier key separately, 
and if you do it must match the signing key
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.

**SecurityConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(
            UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService)  {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring();
    }
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate")
                .permitAll().
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                exceptionHandling()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**OAuth2Config.java**:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private String clientid = "tutorialspoint";
    private String clientSecret = "my-secret-key";
    private String privateKey = "private key";
    private String publicKey = "public key";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(tokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(tokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient(clientid)
                .secret(clientSecret).scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(20000)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(20000);
    }
}
```

**JwtRequestFilter.java**:

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

I tried to change `privateKey` and `publicKey` values to generated online:

```
private String privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
            "Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n" +
            "DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,A033B6E4DCA5218F\n" +
            "\n" +
            "QyTlIaijNU0EQi+DZKcihKNEDREpkG+14bKsrRh2NudDM42K37h6hQWNn859DYLT\n" +
            "J2mdF4ghs2PGZqxRukrsrfIA1VVFoTObGlLQCFXb1L+kH90vDEbB1qdxexedRJZF\n" +
            "NqQ9GXaGmUieGhBnMroSPshKvwmMzPXFcH/eYv/4RIKo9ejeWkx54NZtM1Boy2SE\n" +
            "lHGlZpVxEupKZ9fpw6bcr/TsA0cIuUHRtvf8lwgmBgKBXU9F8c2PhhVgalE2RcJv\n" +
            "q9ujFvF6FU9AtEZsV9+wJznoRrQlY447bnh9qlfI3JyGoz6czX9foeB70CWJM4TF\n" +
            "SZigb7TxhhBVtiIRsA5ILwXuSDQ0TDA08oG9WP5dQ0oplUkGa6AcEQnO4I9y4E3w\n" +
            "3UL314kndgxrgUF+IMDedfMxWHslFNGmz2VVibKtnOZEyjHZG1YqpUOqKP8WdJWS\n" +
            "OzOxkbydUtFoNPJ5V2rd/PNpI0t7sxTa2LUGpvHJXvSXTqQufp3ascnRTOpAQC2H\n" +
            "mjpRGx1SRIJA09WAfpIgGP5Ap6/cZIyZrgAlIQnGpDdOG9A5WRLPb6H2jUiDJnEv\n" +
            "ItNfDNj5fOQiL0tyBW5ulMBBNlRJxyP65XhU7H/6kn3AuW7Qg/znZTAIQnAr9rIY\n" +
            "eb4HUsF176ApezxeKLU+Z4fFNhxUFRB19/CHDjrKoaJxBoVwbH7bFOUP35BLPX5r\n" +
            "gSIlT6UJB/WEiewyhSNaYdvx0YLl7shsoLK/+62n0xoKd0zibDsWzTaNK5p06Mvt\n" +
            "JyHf86/iotOlvMZ/I+LQ7/yL4U1Z3AouZ9srG/VMeEXeHajfyg4Y9L8MTEESnQBV\n" +
            "N1IVCEHcUCg3EthAYWL/3OqcOwbNNfcUmLVH5INuAWyErPjKybCp6iW3ArAoPlUN\n" +
            "qAAqCDRI1V7qCV9nBNHMQlC8m7BuLwoD7kbNTHPOcuhM76ow+Y2jvrhJrkq/pbli\n" +
            "TwE5kDpOc6xIGVRmuxy2yYXmvppYv//GiepT89J0wCWacODVZF75yWO83556rGyn\n" +
            "rnqyMkDpZDqwRG3ktgWZNKDjAbbpcWmyFHobws/ZMKsXQiIuoU03smC3mCw1VMKa\n" +
            "YaRf6mEaa1pzNMqmQlD0aHWYN/9zeeMQHSTb7G2VeSB+yLmBvDeq6kyVoElx8Ark\n" +
            "2/lniftEhO85AAJz5hIEHSqi1MRzyxtb0qPjAB+NzFw2pgifVsEhqBPdvVhI1piZ\n" +
            "/nedPy808+GC/PF1BOR6S4ZdPFOUkRf4OLD3AbXTJsgYn1LAV2mC2lsUrnrWjhhT\n" +
            "jc41TmSue4FMf+s1ADntA+e9JB/uyePh5qrsLBqU6mjiIRf99nZ5qSqlgj6HuxWH\n" +
            "dGvgcZlTS1U5wsWSBDhrWXV703hQs3RSBCJshD44g5+iVneFLRO7fVeX+acK5A8k\n" +
            "+dc5ihVSsKI7wcchdrrta7MYdDNfd+6NlnCeKKhV9Mh9TheaxlVzmmKcUgMeLlqN\n" +
            "aGpojVX07F2HnoRah2Kq3h6C23g1RjO5zLVjJ5ZP5QcUKHqIHkv9Yxiy/IB0PPLp\n" +
            "jvMdn13O+KTiNQut/2IiOWpOIa0BgWVPbEZz5AUFIovztyFZOYDTPAidDGE8wxGK\n" +
            "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    private String publicKey = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCRGhJOZwdDh86Gaai3LLQfMTtNhvKjPElGeFXG/2FgWWRXRRZppAVLL8muWhzayt5mTl9a6eIhtH8qo1bJAdB+0fXErj4bx5ABaoU/O+jCLewLqRo13df+ryz9KLKoyB15JcEORMA6Izqp50mLGlw+vZn/cEc0deTC7GgqxmfzfH9VpbLr2GRB2HTk5oDZOE5uK99L7J5nOuSU7pGIu+RyOEWiXWX65i242wVvjdiBBEGCo1yHGZC7QX+UFHJMCAZzuyPbvnmxsbIkZJyelfQA3zzL8hmP0uEI8KJIqhCPG68FQ09U46G9yZOnOkywEum1sV8extcBtfeiYich1UK5";
```

however deployment now results in

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 
'tokenEnhancer' defined in testproject.security.OAuth2Config: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2
.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter]:
 Factory method 'tokenEnhancer' threw exception;
 nested exception is org.springframework.security.jwt.codec
.InvalidBase64CharacterException: 
Bad Base64 input character decimal 45 in array position 5
        at
```

error

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting proper keys into `JwtAccessTokenConverter`?

Comment: Not sure about it. See edit

Comment: Added an answer below. Hopefully enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're passing in an SSH public key. You need to generate a key pair first, then you can export the public key:

```
$ keytool -genkeypair -alias mytest -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit
$ keytool -list -rfc --keystore keystore.jks | openssl x509 -inform pem -pubkey > pubkey.txt
```

You can load the key:

```
KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
    new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "changeit".toCharArray())
        .getKeyPair("mytest");
```

Your authorization server will use the above `KeyPair` to sign, and resource server will use the public key.